# Cant execute a gulp task in Bamboo

Tags: node.js, git, gulp, bamboo

I have created a Bamboo build plan. The gulp build task i have created, returns this error `'gulp' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`
How do i create a gulp Bamboo task?

Comment: I think you will have to install gulp globally in you bamboo env, before you use it. Try  adding 'npm i -g gulp' command before you perform 'gulp myTask' .

Comment: Try to install gulp globally and try (or) give full path of the gulp file where it is installed

Comment: Install gulp BOTH globally and locally if you haven't.

Comment: I have installed gulp and gulp-cli globally. It works fine on the build server, but when i run it as a Bamboo task i get the `'gulp' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` error. Should i install gulp locally on every build as a part of the build plan?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Bamboo service was running in System context. I needed to add the Path to the gulp-cli `C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\npm\` In the System Path Environment Variable